# Battery is not charging and upower shows full even though its not

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo L13 Yoga.

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Sunwoda
  model:                5B10W13935
  serial:               666
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mi 30 Mär 2022 14:43:14 (32 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              38.33 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         39.8 Wh
    energy-full-design:  46 Wh
    energy-rate:         2.313 W
    voltage:             16.885 V
    percentage:          96%
    capacity:            86.5217%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1648644193  2.313   discharging
```

but

```
§ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
96
§ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
Unknown
```

even though my charger is plugged in.
Does anybody has an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the "wonderful" consequences of different groups of developers having differing opinions of what words mean. Without getting *too* deep into the history of batteries, what you see is the result of at least three different teams:

1. the battery manufacturer's firmware development team
2. the notebook vendor's firmware development team
3. the `upower` development team

Batteries do not all have the same sets of API endpoints. When you are using the `/sys/class/power_supply` "files", you are actually querying the firmware of the device through kernel hooks. These interact with the firmware that was provided by the notebook vendor who, in this case, would be Lenovo. Lenovo gets their batteries from several different suppliers, including Sunwoda, LGC, Shenzen Mingyiyuan Electronics, Sunwind, Bamtop, Dongguan Lewe, Shenzen Glory, and others. Each of these battery manufacturers have different firmware endpoints in their batteries to report things like charge cycles, available voltage, charge limits, and the like. The Lenovo firmware translates the differing endpoints from the battery firmware to a semi-standardized set of endpoints that the Lenovo hardware can use to manage the battery and report information back to the OSes.

With the hardware people out of the way, now we can look at the myriad of developers who have contributed to `upower` over the years, reverse-engineering the endpoints that Lenovo (and other hardware manufacturers) have made available over the years. Because there is rarely any documentation provided by companies, it's up to a developer to look at the data in front of them and work out what various bits mean. In the case of `upower`, this means:

| Hardware API Endpoint | Value in `upower` | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity` | `percentage` | Current battery charge as a percentage (between `0` and `107` ... don't ask) |
| `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/state` | `state` | Current battery activity (`idle`, `charging`, `fully-charged`, `discharging`, `unknown`) |

For my Lenovo X1 Carbon, `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/state` is `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`, because the team that made the firmware for your notebook was not the same as the team that made the firmware for mine. What's interesting is that a notebook can have both a `state` *and* a `status` that conflict with each other, as is the case for my Lenovo W541 and my wife's Toshiba. This can result in `upower` (and Gnome) reporting the wrong state of the battery. My W541 is always fully charged, even when it's not. My wife's Toshiba is always charging, even when the battery is full.

This would naturally raise the question: what values can I trust? Unfortunately, this comes down to which set of developers you feel knows your computer the best. For me, I tend to use the numbers reported by `upower` as a "general vicinity", while the information in `/sys/class/power_supply` is gospel. This isn't always true, particularly for Asus machines, but it has proven to be the most consistent over the years.

Hopefully this clears up some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, I've just now realized that its actually ../status and not state. But my battery is still not charging when i plug in my cable which is the bigger problem...

Answer (score 0):

Another endpoint that is usefull in this case is `energy-rate`.  When charging is really done and external power is available, then this will fall to 0.  Regardless of what `state` or `status` says, this is authoritative as it is the actualy current going into the battery (or out when in discharge) as reported by the BMS chip in the battery.